# How to create an object where value is a function?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I need to programatically create an object that got one pair of property : value like `tmpCol["formatter"]=color` where color is defined like

```
var colors = function backgroundColor(cell, formatterParams){}
```

everything works fine on [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/radek/u48joxv6/101/)

But I need to create the object on the fly and outside the javascript. I using Google Script where I create definition of column headers based on data. I tried to define a dummy function  `var colors = function backgroundColor(cell, formatterParams){}` on the server side so the definition would even pass a run.  But when I run the page in a browser the function definition seems to me to be a text rather a function. The browser makes a call the get the data using `google.script.run` the definition is returned by GAS.

[image]

Typed definition         `tmpCol["formatter"]=colors;` works but not the one when processed by GAS

The html code on server side looks like

```
  <script>
  var colors = function backgroundColor(cell, formatterParams){
    var value = cell.getValue();
    if ("color" in formatterParams) {
      var color = cell.getRow().getData()[formatterParams["color"]];
      if (color){
        cell.getElement().style.backgroundColor = cell.getRow().getData()[formatterParams["color"]];
      }
    }
  return value;
  }
      var initialTableData = [{id:0,name:"nahrávají se data"}];
      var table = new Tabulator("#zz-test", {
          layout:"fitColumns",
          responsiveLayout:"hide",
          data:initialTableData,
          dataTree:true,    
          selectable:true,
          columns:[
            {title:"",
              field:"name",
              headerSort:false,
            },
          ],
      });
google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(updateTable).callLibraryFunction("zzlib.getTabulatorData",'A87J8HRS1');
      
  function updateTable(data){
    table.deleteColumn("name");
    for ( var c = 0; c < data.tableColumns.length; c++){
      table.addColumn(data.tableColumns[c]);
    }
//test
      var tmpCol = {};
    tmpCol["title"]="test 1";
    tmpCol["field"]="test1";
    tmpCol["headerSort"]=false;
    tmpCol["formatter"]=colors;
    tmpCol["formatterParams"]={color:"color1"};    
  
  columns = [
        {title:"", field:"name", width:200},
        tmpCol,
        {title:"Test2", field:"test2", width:200,formatter:colors,formatterParams:{color:"color2"}}
        ];

  //  table.deleteColumn("name");
  //  table.deleteColumn("test1");
  //  table.deleteColumn("test2");

    for ( var c = 0; c < columns.length; c++){
     // table.addColumn(columns[c]);
    }
console.log(columns);
// test
    table.setData(data.tableData); 
  }
    </script>
```

I need to define `formatter` for two columns. So inside the for cycle I tried these so far.

```
for ( var c = 0; c < data.tableColumns.length; c++){
  if ("formatter" in data.tableColumns[c]) {
    //console.log(eval(data.tableColumns[c]["formatter"]));
    //data.tableColumns[c]["formatter"]= new Function("return " +   data.tableColumns[c]["formatter"]);
    data.tableColumns[c]["formatter"]= var colors = new Function("return " + data.tableColumns[c]["formatter"]);
    //eval(data.tableColumns[c]["formatter"]);
    //eval("var colors = " + data.tableColumns[c]["formatter"]);
   console.log("eval");
  }
}
```

Any idea how to create the object value on the server side and pass it correctly to the browser?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have:

```
var functionString = "function backgroundColor(cell, formatterParams){}";
```

You can use `Function` constructor:  #Recommended

```
var colors = new Function("return " + functionString)()
```

This parses our function inside an anonymous function, we add `return` so by calling the anonymous function we can get our target function, and in the end we add the call `()`

example:

```js
var functionString = "function backgroundColor(cell, formatterParams){ return 'Hey!'}";

var anonymousFunction = new Function("return " + functionString);
var targetFunction = anonymousFunction();


console.log(anonymousFunction);
console.log(anonymousFunction());

console.log(targetFunction);
console.log(targetFunction());
```

Read more [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/Function)

or you can use `eval`: # Not Recommended

```
eval("var colors = " + functionString);
```

This one will parse and evaluate your string as a javascript code

However, this is a risky approach, try to avoid it

Read more [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval)

Comment: I  need to run the code definition twice. I need to define two columns. Either of them - Funcition nor eval works for me. Maybe I am doing something wrong. Eval does nothing and when using `new Function("return " + functionString)` table cells got the text of the function not values.

Comment: sorry for the confusion, I've just updated my answer, by using the Function constructor we need to make a call to return the target function itself, so we just need to add `()` at the end, to be `var colors = new Function("return " + functionString)()`

Comment: cool. This one works `new Function("return " + functionString)();` Could you please explain so I can understand. And be patient with me ;-)

Comment: Sure :) I've updated my answer with the explanation